# Socket.io how check connect(android)

Tags: android, socket.io, chat

Sorry for my english. I dont know how check connect to android device. I think its do like this `mSocket.connected()` its return `true` or `false` but its return always `false`. I do like this:

```
//code

try{
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://10.0.0.4:8080");
        }catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.e("connect0", "error");
        }

        mSocket.connect();
        imChat();
//code
}

public void imChat() {

 mSocket.once(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                try {
                 Log.e("connect", "connect");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.toString());
                }

            }
        }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                try {
                    Log.e("disconnect", "disconnect");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });

//always false
Log.e("connect is", String.valueOf(mSocket.connected()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response but others may find this useful:
In answer to your question to check the connection simply

`if (socket.connected()==true){
    //DO STUFF
   }`

You might add some code checking for connection errors or errors in general. Like:

```
         `.on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    for(Object o : args){
                        println "object: " + o.toString()
                        if(o instanceof SocketIOException)
                            ((SocketIOException) o).printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            })`
```